# Android NFC: App launched, but action is not in intent

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to handle URI open for a specific domain through NFC.

The manifest has:

```
<activity android:name="HistoryActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mydomain.me"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mydomain.me"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

onResume and onNewIntent look like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    this.handleNfcBeam(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    setIntent(intent);

    this.handleNfcBeam(intent);
}
```

and handleNfcBeam looks like:

```
protected boolean handleNfcBeam(Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action != null &&
            action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"))
    {

        return true; // todo: process URL
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I beam the right URL, the app is being launched. HOWEVER, action is always null!!

I haven't event gotten to the point where I can actually process the message...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a breakpoint on each of the two lines of `this.handleNfcBeam(intent);` to see which route your intent is coming. Then inspect the intent data to see what kind of intent you received.

Does your tag contain a NDEF message with the right content, matching your definition in the manifest? When you define scheme, host and pathPrefix, then all three of them must be met to trigger the intent.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have enough reputation points to vote you up - - and I have still not resolved the "mystery" so I cannot mark it as answered.

Comment: Did you verify what I mentioned? Especially make sure that your tag contains exactly what you define in your manifest

Comment: The problem was actually with the wrong NDEF message being beamed.